# Extracting section of text with regex in PowerShell and outputting to new file

Tags: powershell

I have a 200MB XML log file, which I would like to essentially filter to a subset of results.

The contents of the log file is made up of elements like so:

```xml
<sample No=1 Name=MyText>blah blah blah</sample>
```

When viewing these in Notepad++ I can find each block of matching text with a regex search of:

```regex
MyText.*?</sample>
```

I have tried the following PowerShell script:

```
$input_path = ‘c:\temp\input.xml’
$output_file = ‘c:\temp\output.xml’
$regex = 'MyText.*?</sample>'
Select-String -Path $input_path -Pattern $regex -AllMatches |
    % { $_.Matches } |
    % { $_.Value } > $output_file
```

I don't get any errors, and output.xml is generated but contains no data. When I perform the same regex search in Notepad++ I get results so I am not sure where I cam going wrong here. I do not get any error messages, however the script seems to complete in a very short time for the amount of data in the file so I am not fully convinced its actually parsing the entire file.

Can anyone suggest where I am going wrong?

Comment: I have tried to recreate your issue from what you have put above, but can't. I get output in the file. Does the expected data output to the console if you remove the redirection to `$output_file`? I can only suggest that you try piping the output to [Out-File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?view=powershell-6) with the appropriate encoding.

Comment: **[DO NOT parse XML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1630171).** Use a proper XML parser instead.

Comment: while it pro'ly is not the cause of your glitch, you have typographic quotes in your 1st two lines. those can cause very strange problems ... you likely otta change them to standard, straight quotes.

Comment: Ok it appears to be an issue with my regex. Doing MyText(.*)((.|\n)*) does return results, but as soon as I add in </sample> after I get no results. Does regex work differently in Powershell? When I try the same pattern in regextester and notepad++ I get results no problem, so looks like Powershell doesn't want to search more than one line?

Comment: If you want the regex `.` character to match line feed characters, you need to use the single line modifier `s` like so `'(?s)MyText.*?</sample>'`